# Using simple fragments to switch between activities

Tags: android, android-fragments

### I have used fragments

**activity_fragment_demo.xml**

```
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:orientation="vertical"
    tools:context=".FragmentDemo" >

    <LinearLayout
        android:layout_width="fill_parent"
        android:layout_height="fill_parent"
        android:orientation="vertical" >

        <LinearLayout
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content" >

            <Button
                android:id="@+id/button1"
                android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:layout_weight="1"
                android:text="Button" />

            <Button
                android:id="@+id/button2"
                android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:layout_weight="1"
                android:text="Button" />

        </LinearLayout>

        <LinearLayout
            android:id="@+id/simple_fragment"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="match_parent"
            android:orientation="vertical" >
        </LinearLayout>
    </LinearLayout>

</LinearLayout>
```

**FragmentDemo.java**

```
public class FragmentDemo extends FragmentActivity implements OnClickListener {

    Button b1, b2;

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_fragment_demo);

        b1 = (Button) findViewById(R.id.button1);
        b2 = (Button) findViewById(R.id.button2);
        b1.setOnClickListener(this);
        b2.setOnClickListener(this);
    }

    @Override
    public boolean onCreateOptionsMenu(Menu menu) {
        // Inflate the menu; this adds items to the action bar if it is present.
        getMenuInflater().inflate(R.menu.fragment_demo, menu);
        return true;
    }

    @Override
    public void onClick(View v) {
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub
        switch (v.getId()) {
        case R.id.button1:

            addFragment(new F1(this), false,
                    FragmentTransaction.TRANSIT_FRAGMENT_OPEN);

            break;
        case R.id.button2:
            addFragment(new F2(this), false,
                    FragmentTransaction.TRANSIT_FRAGMENT_OPEN);

            break;

        default:
            break;
        }

    }

    void addFragment(Fragment fragment, boolean addToBackStack, int transition) {
        FragmentTransaction ft = getSupportFragmentManager().beginTransaction();
        ft.replace(R.id.simple_fragment, fragment);
        ft.setTransition(transition);
        if (addToBackStack)
            ft.addToBackStack(null);
        ft.commit();
    }

}
```

**F1.java**

```
public class F1 extends Fragment {

    Context c;
    View v;

    public F1(FragmentDemo fragmentDemo) {
        // TODO Auto-generated constructor stub
        this.c = fragmentDemo;
    }

    @Override
    public View onCreateView(LayoutInflater inflater, ViewGroup container,
            Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub

        v = inflater.inflate(R.layout.f1, container, false);

        return v;
    }

}
```

**F2.java**

```
public class F2 extends Fragment {
    Context c;
    View v;

    public F2(FragmentDemo fragmentDemo) {
        // TODO Auto-generated constructor stub
        this.c = fragmentDemo;
    }

    @Override
    public View onCreateView(LayoutInflater inflater, ViewGroup container,
            Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub

        v = inflater.inflate(R.layout.f2, container, false);

        return v;
    }
}
```

---

**OUTPUT SCREEN: -- > WHEN I CLICK BUtton on lefthand side**

[image]

**Similarly for next button**

[image]

---

Now HOW CAN I Merge the thow buttons like below

[image]

Using fragments i have used .....

- If i click on button once `Activity`-`A1` must display in button
  below .....
- similarly If i click on button again `Activity`-`A2` must display
  below
- Then if i click on third time ...... `Activity`-`A1` must display
  again

**A Boolean nature of single button that repeats its cycle !**

---

**How to achieve this !**

Comment: Keep track of the state `onClick { booleanNature = !booleanNature; }`

Comment: Can you please edit my mainActivity as ur answer .... an example would help .... i am a newbie

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your `Activity` could keep track of the state with a `boolean`. For example like this:

```
   private boolean state = false;

   @Override
    public void onClick(View v) {
        switch (v.getId()) {
        case R.id.button1:
            state = !state;
            if (state) {
            addFragment(new F2(this), false,
                    FragmentTransaction.TRANSIT_FRAGMENT_OPEN);
            } else {
            addFragment(new F1(this), false,
                    FragmentTransaction.TRANSIT_FRAGMENT_OPEN);
            }
            break;
        default:
            break;
        }

    }
```

Answer (score 1):

There are many ways to do this but here is a simple solution.

First change activity_fragment_demo.xml

```
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:orientation="vertical"
    tools:context=".FragmentDemo" >

    <LinearLayout
        android:layout_width="fill_parent"
        android:layout_height="fill_parent"
        android:orientation="vertical" >

        <FrameLayout
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content" 
            android:layout_gravity="center_horizontal">

            <Button
                android:id="@+id/button1"
                android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:text="Button" />

            <Button
                android:id="@+id/button2"
                android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:text="Button" 
                android:visibility="gone"/>

        </FrameLayout>

        <LinearLayout
            android:id="@+id/simple_fragment"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="match_parent"
            android:orientation="vertical" >
        </LinearLayout>
    </LinearLayout>

</LinearLayout>
```

next in FragmentDemo.java just change your onClick method like this:

```
@Override
    public void onClick(View v) {
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub
        switch (v.getId()) {
        case R.id.button1:

            addFragment(new F1(this), false,
                FragmentTransaction.TRANSIT_FRAGMENT_OPEN);
            b1.setVisibility(View.GONE);
            b2.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);

            break;
        case R.id.button2:
            addFragment(new F2(this), false,
                FragmentTransaction.TRANSIT_FRAGMENT_OPEN);

            b2.setVisibility(View.GONE);
            b1.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);
            break;

        default:
            break;
        }
    }
```

Comment: Your welcome, the first answer is great too but only covers if switching between 2 fragments (which is what you asked). But this method could be used to cycle through 2+ fragments. Just add more buttons and fragments.